# Proving a map is injective iff it has a left inverse

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f:A\to B$

Prove the map $f$ is injective iff it has a left inverse.

Starting with $f$ is injective

Let $A$ not be $ \varnothing$

$f(A) = \{b \in B \ | \ b = f(a) \text{ for some } a \in A\}$

If there is a map $g: B \to A$ defined by $g(B) = \{a \in A \ | \ a = g(b)\text{ for some } b \in B\}$ where $b = f(a)$

The composite function $g \circ f(a): a \to f(a) \to a$ returns the identity on $A$ and is thus a left inverse.

$g$ does not exist in this definition if $g(b_i) \neq a_i$ for some $i$ denoting an element of $A,B$, which makes it the nullset

Or

$g(b_i) = a_i = a_{i+x}$ two or more elements of $A$ share an element of $B$ in the mapping of $f: A \to B$ It cannot be true because $a_i \neq a_{i+x}$ implies $f(a_i) \neq f(a_{i+x})$

Comment: The statement is actually incorrect. $f\colon\varnothing\to\{\star\}$ is injective, but has no left inverse. You need to assume $A\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming your sets are finite. You should not. The assertion that if $f$ is injective then $|A|\leq|f(A)|$ is immediate by the definition of cardinality. "Since the domain is less than or equal to the codomain" is incoherent. Sets are not "less" or "more" than other sets. "Each element of $A$ maps to exactly $1$ or more elements in $f(A)$". Just one: because $f$ is a function; it has nothing to do with cardinalities or sizes. You need the right inverse to be defined in all of $B$, not just $f(A)$. Your explanation is insufficient, IMHO. And you only tried one direction.

Comment: That is, you only tried to show that if $f$ is injective then it has a left inverse (but haven't quite managed it). You did not even try to show that if $f$ has a left inverse, then it is injective. Yet the statement you are trying to establish says "iff", which is (in my opinion pernicious, but often used) short of "if and only if". You tried the "only if" direction, but haven't even gotten started on the "if" direction.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited my answer, is this more of what you're looking for?

Comment: So... What's the question?

Comment: This is still a mess. A function is injective if whenever $a_1,a_2$ are in the domain, and $a_1\neq a_2$, then $f(a_1)\neq f(a_2)$. This is *the definition*. It matters not one whit whether the domain is empty or not. The reason the empty set comes into play is that the statement you claim to be proving **is false**: a function with empty domain and nonempty codomain is necessarily injective, *but does not have a left inverse*. Your use of "$f^{-1}f$" when trying to define an inverse is about as bad a notation as someone writing $2+\times3$.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) It's not "similarly", it's conversely, and the argument in that paragraph is convoluted and unclear. It is difficult to tell what you are assuming, what you are asserting and then proving, what you are first proving and then concluding. I would probably give no more than one third partial credit to a write-up like this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your feedback. I want to make proofs of trivial stuff as simple as possible, so I may have been skipping over steps. I didn't mean to make it seem like the domain being non empty implies injectivity. I just wanted to show that it was a condition for the proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If you have some spare time I tried making more sense with the first part, I don't have the time to do the converse again right now, but I'll do it if it'll make me better at maths.

Comment: @RonaldVilliers: The problem isn't whether you skip trivial stuff, the problem is when you say things that make no sense or that are just plain wrong. So implying that this is why you are having issues is rationalization that in fact just tells me you are even more confused than you think you are.  Note that you still claim to be proving a statement that is **false**.  If you are going to add a hypothesis (such as that $A$ is nonempty), then it needs to be **in the statement**, not thrown in ex nihilo in the "proof". I stopped there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be injective.
We construct a left-inverse for $f:A\to B$.

Let $a\in A\neq\emptyset$ be an arbitrary element.

Now take
$g: B\to A$, $b\mapsto \begin{cases} f^{-1}(b),\text{if $b\in\mathrm{Im}f$}\\ a,\text{else}\end{cases}$.

Where $f^{-1}(b)$ notes the single element of $f^{-1}(\{b\})$, as justified further below.

This function is well-defined, as every element $b\in B$ has an image in $A$, and the image is unique, so $b$ does not get mapped onto several different elements in $A$. Here the assumption that $f$ is injective comes in, as this implies that every element in the image of $f$ has exactly one preimage. So $f^{-1}(b)$ (which is the set (not to confuse with a function) of all elements in $A$ with $f(a)=b$).

Now we have $g(f(a))=a$ for every $a\in A$, as $f(a)$ clearly is an element in $\mathrm{Im}f$ (image of $f$).

So $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$.

For the converse:

Let $g$ be a leftinverse of $f$. We have to show that $f$ is injective.

So let $f(a)=f(a')$. We have to show that $a=a'$.

We have $g(f(a))=a$, as $g$ is a leftinverse.
Also we get $g(f(a'))=a'$ for the same reason.

But $a=g(f(a))\stackrel{f(a)=f(a')}{=}g(f(a')=a'$. So $f$ is indeed injective.

Comment: It seems like begging the question if you say you are "constructing a left inverse for $f$", and use the notation $f^{-1}$ in the definition, given that by definition "$f^{-1}$" is supposed to represent the two-sided inverse of $f$ (when it exists). Worse when you then say that $f^{-1}(b)$ is "the set", because then $g$ takes values in $A\cup P(A)$, not $A$. You should either first define the symbol, or better yet define $g$ by saying that $b$, in the case when $b\in \mathrm{Im}(f)$, is mapped to $a$ where $f(a)=b$. The fact that $f$ is injective yields that this is well-defined.

Comment: If you are trying to use the induced function on subsets, note that the induced function from $P(B)$ to $P(A)$ takes subsets of $B$ as arguments, not elements. So if you want to define $g(b)$ as the unique preimage of $b$, then the proper notation would be that it is the unique element of $f^{-1}(\{b\})$, not $f^{-1}(b)$.

Comment: I agree, that the notation might lead to confusion. I wanted to avoid naming the left inverse $f^{-1}$. I am aware that the proper notation would be $f^{-1}(\{b\})$. I have pointed that out, that this is supposed to be a set, as I feel like writing the set as an argument is an overkill, and normally one abuses notation in the case of a singleton. Nevertheless I agree with your critique, as this answer is supposed to be as understandable as possible for a beginner, and I will change the notation.

Comment: I was so confused on this, but essentially since the composite map is only defined when $f(a)$ is an element of the image of $f$, then there is no issue that $g$ is defined as also "acting" on elements not in the image of $f$. I wasn't sure how else to word this. So then we are left with the identity map regardless, right?

Comment: @DerekLuna Thanks for your question. The function constructed above is a left-inverse, so we have $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$. So lets check: For $a\in A$, we have to compute $g\circ f(a)=g(f(a))$. As $f(a)$ lies in the image of $f$, we are in the first case, and always are when we compose with $f$ (I think this is what you mean). So this means, that we have to evaluate $g(f(a))=f^{-1}(\{f(a)\})$ by construction. Note that this makes sense as $f$ is injective. So the image of $a$ under $f$ (denoted by $f(a)$) has exactly one preimage, namely $a$. So $g(f(a))=a$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Say $f$ is injective.  Then for any $a, b$ in the domain of $f$, we have $f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$.  Thus, "the element that maps onto $x$" is uniquely defined for any $x$ in the codomain of $f$.  Call this element $f^{-1}(x)$ - we see clearly that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$, so we have a well-defined left-inverse.

Say $f$ has a left-inverse $f^{-1}$.  Let $f(a) = f(b)$.  Applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides, we get $a = b$ (we know the left-inverse must be injective, or else $f$ would not be well-defined).  Thus $f$ is injective.